# В поле эмбеда author вместо тега undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Хочу сделать команду avatar, и вроде всё работает, но в поле автора вместо тега, отправляет `undefined`
Код:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name : 'avatar',
    category : 'utility',
    description : 'Отправляет ваш аватар',
    run : async(client, message, args) => {
      const avatar1 = new MessageEmbed()
      .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ size: 512, dynamic: true, format: 'png'}))
      .setColor('2f3236')
      let user =
        message.mentions.members.first() ||
        message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
        if (!user)
          return message.channel.send({embeds: [avatar1]})
      const avatar = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(`${user.tag}`, `${user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png'})}`)
      .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 512, dynamic: true, format: 'png'}))
      .setColor('2f3236')

  message.channel.send({ embeds: [avatar]})
}
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладкой. Посмотрите что в этот момент содержит `user` и есть ли у него поле `tag`.